# i have error in R.java?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Please help me ,I convert the file PSD to Android xml file by exportkit ,Then came the mistakes
     How do I remove these mistakes ?
     and What is the reason for mistakes ?

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3oDr.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDyhn.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ0qc.png
```

```
                    <ImageView android:id="@+id/layer_2"
                        android:src="@drawable/layer_2"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/ek_img_content"
                         android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="219dp"
                        android:layout_width="550dp"
                        android:layout_height="398dp" />

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/first_app"
                        android:fontFamily="Tahoma"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textSize="34sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/first_app_color"
                        android:layout_marginStart="164dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
                        android:layout_width="148dp"
                        android:layout_height="52dp"
                        android:text="@string/first_app_string"
                         />

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/good_luck"
                        android:fontFamily="Tahoma"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:textSize="34sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/first_app_color"
                        android:layout_marginStart="142dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="684dp"
                        android:layout_width="171dp"
                        android:layout_height="52dp"
                        android:text="@string/good_luck_string"
                         />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
     </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: try rebuilding or perform a clean on the project

Comment: make sure you do not have number in layout name as in your first image R.layout.APP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Try this:
      .xml file name should be small letters only allowed
  Change: App1.xml to app.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Clean Project and Rebuilt your project.